# Meaning and implementation of loc[~*value*]

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

Watching this piece of code in the book:

```
def split_train_test_by_id(data, test_ratio, id_column, hash=hashlib.md5):
ids = data[id_column]
in_test_set = ids.apply(lambda id_: test_set_check(id_, test_ratio, hash))
return data.loc[~in_test_set], data.loc[in_test_set]
```

Never saw this loc[~<..>] before. Probably understanding the functionality, however want to be sure. Also is it working only in pandas or python in general?

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators - It is a bitwise NOT

Comment: It works in general, but not when indexing lists (the example you give is NumPy.Pandas specific). Try ~0 in the Python prompt, and variants.

Comment: thanks, both comments as well as answer below helped a lot actually. Got it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw some great comments above, but wanted to make sure that it's clear for a beginner. The `~` flips 1s to 0s and 0s to 1s. It is commonly used with pandas to signify not. In your example, `~in_test_set` is similar to saying `not in_test_set`. The advantage to `~` is that it works with a set of values and is not limited to a single value. See the [Python wiki on bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).